# Java Collection Sort: Issue while sorting list

Tags: java, sorting, collections

This question has been asked many times what i understood is it should return 0 as well with 1 and -1 but still I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:895)  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:512)  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:453)  
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:250)  
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)  
        at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)  
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

Code snippet

```
Collections.sort(List, new Comparator < Employee > () {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        int compareVal = 0;
        int returnVal = 0;
        try {
            if (emp1 == emp2) {
                returnVal = 0;
            } else {
                if (empName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.EMP_ID)) {
                    if (emp1.getEmpCode() != null && emp2.getEmpCode() != null) {
                        compareVal = emp1.getEmpCode().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getEmpCode());
                    }
                } else {
                    compareVal = 5;
                }

                if (compareVal > 0) {
                    returnVal = 1;
                } else if (compareVal < 0) {
                    returnVal = -1;
                } else if (compareVal == 0) {
                    returnVal = 0;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
});
```

Comment: The code in its current state is syntactically incorrect. You have a dangling `else`. Please fix your code.

Comment: There are lots of details missing from your question. What property of Employee is your basis for comparing? What is empName in this context? We don't see it initialized anywhere. What is empCode? Looks like it's a string. The code looks messy, too. Please give us more details so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also has something to do with the version of JDK. If it does well in JDK6, maybe it will have the problem in JDK 7 described by you, because the implementation method in jdk 7 has been changed.

Look at this:

Description: The sorting algorithm used by java.util.Arrays.sort and (indirectly) by java.util.Collections.sort has been replaced. The new sort implementation may throw an IllegalArgumentException if it detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract. The previous implementation silently ignored such a situation. If the previous behavior is desired, you can use the new system property, java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort, to restore previous mergesort behaviour.

I don't know the exactly reason. However, if you add the code before you use sort. It will be OK.

```
System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried cleaning up your code and adding some of my own insights to it. Seeing that you're using Employee.getEmpCode() as a sorting basis, you probably should do `emp1.getEmpCode().equals(emp2.getEmpCode())` instead of `emp1 == emp2`. Not sure what you're doing exactly, but this does what your function does without the local variables.

```
Collections.sort(List, new Comparator < Employee > () {
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        try {
            if (emp1.getEmpCode().equals(emp2.getEmpCode()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                if (empName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.EMP_ID)) {
                    if (emp1.getEmpCode() != null && emp2.getEmpCode() != null) {
                        return emp1.getEmpCode().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getEmpCode());
                    }
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```